# jq process json where an element can be an array or object

Tags: json, jq

The output from the tool I am using is creating an element in the json that is an object when there is only 1 item but an array when there is more than 1.

How do I parse this with jq to return the full list of names only from within content?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "data block1",
      "content": {
        "name": "1 bit of data"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "data block2",
      "content": [
        {
          "name": "first bit"
        },
        {
          "name": "another bit"
        },
        {
          "name": "last bit"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I can't work out is how to switch depending on the type of `content`.

```
# jq '.data[].content.name' test.json
"1 bit of data"
jq: error (at test.json:22): Cannot index array with string "name"
# jq '.data[].content[].name' test.json
jq: error (at test.json:22): Cannot index string with string "name"
```

I am sure I should be able to use `type` but my jq-fu is not strong enough!

```
# jq '.data[].content | type=="array"' test.json
false
true
```

---

jq version 1.5

Comment: I don't think so. I that case `comments` is always an object.

Comment: I see what you mean, I can search the tree for name. Maybe I made the example too simple. The json tree I am processing is very large and I want to be able to select multiple elements from each `content` section and line them up with the parent block.

Comment: If the example isn't illustrative of your real problem, please edit the question to show the _actual_ representation of your JSON, so that people can attempt to answer it

Comment: Updated to be more explicit but without making it too complex. The key is I am looking for some kind of if/else in jq. Maybe I need to process the file twice to remove this edge case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jq '.data[].content | if type == "array" then .[] else . end | .name?'
```

(The trailing ? is there just in case.)

More succinctly:

```
jq '.data[].content | .name? // .[].name?'
```

Comment: Perfect! How did I miss these `jq` docs the first time I googled this https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons . And ? on it's own would have been enough for me to solve this in 2 passes!